# Mongoid storing Array, for Hash defaulted field

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a Hash field with default value as empty Hash `field :host, :type => Hash, :default=> {}`. When I save a record with no value for host, it stores it as an blank array instead of blank Hash.

Following is the document

```
{
    "created_at": ISODate("2012-05-21T14:56:16.0Z"),
    "host": [

    ],
    "short_title": "Ok ok",
    "title": "Test Title",
    "updated_at": ISODate("2012-05-23T07:22:40.0Z")
}`
```

Comment: `{
    "created_at": ISODate("2012-05-21T14:56:16.0Z"),
    "host": [
        
    ],
    "short_title": "Ok ok",
    "title": "Test Title",
    "updated_at": ISODate("2012-05-23T07:22:40.0Z")
}`

Comment: Can't reproduce on my machine.

Comment: I actually have a multistep form. I add data other than host in first step and save it. Then add host in next step.

Comment: So, look for something that saves empty array to your `host`.

Comment: Agreed. Because MongoDB is schemaless, there's nothing to enforce the datatype on that field. You are probably setting the field to an empty array in your controllers somewhere.